# Modular comparison of characters

Tags: java, math, ascii, string-comparison

This seems like a very simple question, but there's surprisingly little written about it on the Internet, and I'm having a hard time implementing it correctly on my own. What is the best way to implement a modular *comparison* function on ASCII characters in Java, such that the comparison "wraps around" the end of the alphabet? I want to use it for a "between" function that can partition the entire alphabet at arbitrary locations, and correctly return "true" when asked if 'y' is between 'x' and 'b'.

I've already found all the questions and answers that talk about modular *arithmetic* on characters, so I know how to do modular addition (character shifting) with code like this:

```
char shifted = (((original - 'a') + 1) % 26) + 'a';
```

However, this is based on Java's built in modular arithmetic functions, which have no equivalent for comparison. Even if I was using plain ints, I have no way of asking Java if a < b < c mod 26 (which should return true if a = 24, b = 25, and c = 1).

So the general question is, what's the best way to implement modular *comparison* operations in Java? If that's too hard a problem, is there at least a way to get such comparisons to work for the ASCII alphabet?

Comment: Note that “modular comparison” doesn't make sense for a binary comparison: there is no “less-than” order in modular arithmetic. A “between” thing is still possible, though, so your question remians valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In testing for `A < B < C` in a circular queue, you can always assume `A <= B` and has either wrapped around or not.

If `A < B`, no wrapping has occurred.  If either `B < C or C < A`, then B is between A and C.

If `A > B`, then you've wrapped.  If `B < C and C < A`, then B is between A and C.

You'll need to define for yourself how to handle A==B, B==C, or A==C.

Comment: This is brilliantly simple. The best part is that it doesn't depend on the length of the alphabet, so I can use the same function even if my string could contain punctuation or Unicode characters without having to change the magic number 26.

Comment: It would also work well for alphabets with values that are comparable, but not necessarily contiguous from end to end, such as hexadecimal or base64.

Answer (score 1):

So your question is: is character `c_1` between characters `c_2` and `c_3`, provided that the alphabet wraps around?

- Convert each character to a number (i.e, `a = 1`, `b = 2`, ..., `z = 26`). In your example, that would be `c_1 = 'y' = 25` between `c_2 = 'x' = 24` and `c_3 = 'b' = 2`).
- If `c_3 < c_2`, add 26 to `c_3`. In your example, that is the case because `2 < 24`.
- We now have `c_1 = 25`, `c_2 = 24`, and `c_3 = 28`.
- Check if `c_1 >= c_2 && c_1 <= c_3` holds. If it does then the character is between the two bounds. If it does not hold then continue with the next step.
- Add 26 to `c_1` and check if this value satisfies the above check. If it does then the character is within the wrapped bounds. If it does not then stop.

In this approach, you're basically adding 26 to the 'second' alphabet. So:

```
... 23 24 25 26 1 2 3 4
```

becomes:

```
... 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

You can then do arithmetic as you would normally do.

**Edit**: Updated algorithm based on MvG's comment. There are indeed multiple situations: "is 25 between 24 and 2?" but also "is 1 between 24 and 2?". In the latter case, you also need to check if (1 + 26) is between 24 and (2 + 26) - and this holds so the character 'a' is indeed between 'x' and 'b'.

Comment: You should also add 26 to `c_1` and see if that is within the range.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your tastes, you may want to use modulus operators rather than if statements. To perform the comparison in a single line, do something like this:

```
public static boolean isStrictlyBetween(char a, char x, char b) {
    // assuming x, a, and b are all the same case (lower or upper).
    return ((x - a + 26) % 26) < ((b - a + 26) % 26);
}
```

This code says to return true if the clockwise distance from a to x is less than the clockwise distance from a to b. The +26 assures that the difference expression's result is positive (% of negative numbers performs strangely in some languages).  The % 26 performs your desired modulus.